# Ordinal arithmetic and functions

Tags: functions, logic, set-theory, ordinals

I have two function $G$ and $F$ defined on ordinals and I know that

$$G(\alpha +\omega )\subseteq F(\gamma +\alpha+\omega)$$ when $G(\alpha)\subseteq F(\gamma)$ and $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal. I also know that $G(\omega)\subseteq F(\omega)$ and that $G$ and $F$ are increasing functions.

I have to prove that

1. If $\lambda <\omega$ then $G(\omega^\lambda)\subseteq F(\omega^{2(\lambda-1)}$).
2. If $\lambda=\omega^\alpha c$ where $\alpha\geq 1$, $1\leq c<\omega$, then $G(w^\lambda)\subseteq F(\omega^{\omega^\alpha(2c-1)})$
3. If otherwise $c\geq \omega$, then $G(\omega^\lambda)\subseteq F(\omega^{\lambda 2})$

I've proved the first but the second and third elude my abilities.

About the second.
I've tried by induction (setting $\alpha=1$ to try to see the general reasonment). But, assume the property true for $c$ and prove it for $c+1$: $$G(\omega^{\omega(c+1)})=G(\omega^{\omega c+\omega})=\cup G(\omega^{\omega c+n})$$

Now I thinked to do induction on $n$ but it seems to me that things go worse.

Have you some hints for me?

Comment: Are there any continuity/monotonicity assumptions about $F,G$?

Comment: Yes, I forgot! They are increasing functions.

Comment: And continuous? You seem to be assuming continuity when you write $G(\omega^{\omega c+\omega})=\cup G(\omega^{\omega c+n})$. Otherwise, left hand side could be much larger than right hand side, even if $G$ is increasing. Also, are they perchance ordinal valued? Or just set-valued? This is important information, you should not neglect to add it to the question.

Comment: Well this is a question extrapolated out of its real contex 
which is the paper

http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/479/art%253A10.1007%252FBF01896429.pdf?auth66=1412075234_71a3f8d199afa5cc709c19881cc00d59&ext=.pdf

 (pg. 4)
The functions $G$ and $F$ are functions from ordinals to (chain of) subgroups of a group.

About continuity, I really do not know but I do not think it plays an important role.